# format strings and math in here document

Tags: ruby

This is really two questions combined.

First is: Is there any way to do math inside of a here document?

Second: Is there any way to use format strings in a here document? 
An example of this second question is this:

```
print <<HERE
%s
HERE
% 'string'
```

yet that doesn't work.

Thankss

Comment: If you want a templating system, perhaps you should consider Erb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your first question.  Yes you can do math in a HERE doc.  You would just use the standard #{} expression evaluation.

```
<<EOF
This is a 
multiline doc
with some math in it.
#{3 *18}
EOF
```

In answer to your second question; you can not do string interpolation in the way you are showing in your example within a HERE doc.  Consider the way it is evaluated.  It is treated more like a stream that is instantly evaluated when the document is ended.

Typically I would just create your other variables prior to the HERE doc and then use the standard expression evaluation within your HERE doc.

If you want to format your strings directly in the HERE doc it needs to go at the beginning as @sawa pointed out.  Notice in the following example how I'm passing multiple strings in an array fashion.

```
<<EOF % ['string','string2','string3']
%s
%s
%s
HERE
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes to both. By default, heredoc does interpolation with `#{}`. You can put any Ruby code inside it, and have it evaluated. (To avoid interpolation, you can do `<<'HERE'`.) For your second part, you have the syntax wrong. You should do:

```
print <<HERE % 'string'
%s
HERE
```